# How do I select group wise from a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This one is hard to explain and I'm sure I will facepalm when I see the solution, but I just can't get it right...

I have three tables:

**Table A** contains new records that I want to do something with.

**Table B** contains all activities from Table C *of a specific type* (done beforehand).

**Table C** is sort of a "master" table that contains all activities as well as a customer id and a lot of other stuff.

I need to select all activities that is in Table A from Table B. So far so good.
The part I can't get together is that I also need all the activities from Table B *that has the same customer id as an activity contained in Table A*.

**This is what I'm after:**

```
activity
2
3
4
5
6
```

The trick here is to get activity 2, because activity 2 is also done by *customer* 2, even though it is not in Table A.

Here are the tables:

**Table A** (new records)

```
activity
3
4
5
6
```

**Table B** (all records of a specific type from Table C)

```
activity
1
2   <-- How do I get this record as well?
3
4
5
6
```

**Table C** (all records)

```
activity    customer
1           1
2           2
3           2
4           3
5           3
6           4
7           5
```

I tried something like this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM    table_b b
INNER JOIN table_c c
    ON  c.activity = b.activity
INNER JOIN table_a a
    ON  a.activity = b.activity
```

... but of course it only yields:

```
activity
3
4
5
6
```

How can I get activity 2 as well here?

Comment: `I need to select all activities that is in Table A from Table B` - is this regardless of the customerID... meaning that you want all activities from B that are in A even if the customer ID of A does not match the customer ID of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this returning one column I would recommend staging the customer_ids of activities in Table_b that are in Table_a into a CTE (common table expression [MSDN CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)) then select activities in table_c and join to the CTE to get only activities with a valid customer_id.

example of CTE: (Note the semi-colon `;` before the `WITH` keyword is workaround for an issue in SQL 2005 with multiple statements. It it not necessary if you are in a newer version, or not running batch statements.)

```
;WITH cte_1 AS (
                SELECT distinct c.customer --(only need a distinct result of customer ids)
                from table_b b 
                join table_a a on b.activity = a.activity --(gets only activities in b that are in a)
                join table_c c on b.activity = c.activity --(gets customer id of activies in table b)
)
SELECT a.activity
FROM table_c a
JOIN cte_1 b ON a.customer = b.customer
```

Alternatively you could do this in three joins with a select distinct. However I find the CTE to be an easier way to develop and think about this problem regardless of the way you decide to implement your solution. Although the three join solution will most likely scale and perform better over time with a growing data-set.

Example:

```
SELECT distinct d.activity
from table_b b 
join table_a a on b.activity = a.activity --(gets only activities in b that are in a)
join table_c c on b.activity = c.activity --(gets customer id of activies in table b)
join table_c d ON c.customer = d.customer
```

Both would output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Excellent answer! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I really like three join solution. I don't know why you think the CTE solution would be easier to develop. Would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Roger Thank you, and what I mean by develop is more about how you think about how to answer the problem. I knew it could be done with three joins but It was easier to see the answer after I separated the two concerns of the problem with the CTE. So merely a way of processing the problem. When it comes to deploying this code to production or in actual use the three join is the better answer as it will perform way better and scale to some degree. If you look at my comment on MotoGP's answer I did a query plan and statistic analysis of the three solutions and three joins performs best.

Comment: I see your point. It is a tad harder to swallow the part where table_c is "joining itself" in the three join solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableB b1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Tablec c1
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM   TableA a
                                     INNER JOIN Tablec c
                                             ON a.activity = c.activity
                              WHERE  c.customer = c1.customer)
                      AND c1.activity = b1.activity)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I compared the statistics and query plans (without index) between your answer and my second answer using three joins. The three joins out performs this method on the table scans by 20% cost per scan due to a total only 4 logical reads across all scans compared to 21 logical reads. I created a clustered index on table_c  as a test and the performance different was about the same. What I am asking is why would you use this method... do you know something I don't?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I decided to go with Johns solution as I thought it was a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing a left join?

```
SELECT * 
FROM    table_b b
INNER JOIN table_c c
    ON  c.activity = b.activity
LEFT JOIN table_a a
    ON  b.activity = a.activity
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. That will also give me activity 1, which is not in Table A and that is not a customer that has an activity in Table A.